# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Login issue after suspend / inactivity

Tags: 22.04, suspend, lenovo, login-screen

Sometimes i can't login after screen lock due to inactivity or suspend. I type in password, it processes 5 seconds and then clears out the password. Trying several times doesn't work. Only after restart i can login. I couldn't figure out frequency and reason of it, for me its totally random.
My laptop is: Lenovo Lenovo IdeaPad S540-14IWL.
Thank you in advance!